# Neurotransmitter distribution in the central nervous system (CNS)

Tags: brain, neurotransmitter, central-nervous-system

I have been glancing through the article
[Wikipedia (Neurotransmitter)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurotransmitter)
where in particular at the bottom "diseases and disorders" there is some minor information about an example, but I'm actually looking for a (big) table or list to see where in which regions of the CNS=brain + spinal cord which neurotransmitters are the most prevalent in density. Maybe even ordered with significance?

There seem to be snippets here and there for example

[Nature - Distribution of Dopamine D2-like Receptors in the Human Thalamus](https://www.nature.com/articles/1300336.pdf?origin=ppub)

but I don't seem able to find proper literature which compactly summarizes this topic. I can not believe there is none... Can somebody help me?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92082/discussion-on-question-by-diger-neurotransmitter-distribution-in-the-central-ner).